# Error accessing the 2nd element when iterating on the loop, SELENIUM Python

Tags: python, selenium-chromedriver, web-crawler

I've tried to preserve the DOM, but it doesn't work. I've tried time sleep and wait times, but I still get the same error.

work. I've tried time sleep and wait times, but I still get the same error.

error message : An error occurred: Message: stale element reference: stale element not found

I hope you can help me get that code working properly.

```
import os.path
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.service import Service
from webdriver_manager.chrome import ChromeDriverManager
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By

import urllib.request
import time
import ssl
from selenium.common import exceptions

ssl._create_default_https_context = ssl._create_unverified_context

URL = "https://m.kbsec.com/go.able?linkcd=s060200020000"
IMG_COUNT = 5


def set_chrome_driver():
    options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
    options.add_argument("headless")  
    options.add_argument("lang=ko_KR") 
    options.add_experimental_option(
        "excludeSwitches", ["enable-logging"]
    ) 
    options.add_argument("start-maximized")
    options.add_argument("disable-infobars")
    options.add_argument("--disable-extensions")

    driver = webdriver.Chrome(
        service=Service(ChromeDriverManager().install()), options=options
    )
    return driver


def get_events():
    # Get scroll height
    last_height = driver.execute_script("return document.body.scrollHeight")
   
    idx = 1
    while True:
        html_events = driver.find_elements(By.XPATH, '// *[ @ id = "bbsList"] / li')

        print("===================")
        print(f"{idx} count : " + str(len(html_events)))
     
        idx += 1
        if len(html_events) >= 1000:
            break
        driver.execute_script("window.scrollTo(0, document.body.scrollHeight);")

        # Wait to load page
        time.sleep(3)

        # Calculate new scroll height and compare with last scroll height
        new_height = driver.execute_script("return document.body.scrollHeight")
        if new_height == last_height:
            break
        last_height = new_height

    return html_events


if __name__ == "__main__":

     start = time.time()  

    data = []

    driver = set_chrome_driver()
    driver.get(URL)

    html_events = get_events()

    # save img files to disk
    for event in html_events:
        try:

            print(event.text)
            split_text = event.text.split("\n")
            # title_period
            save_path = "./images/" + split_text[0]
            href = event.find_element(By.CSS_SELECTOR, 'a')
            href.get_attribute('href')
            href.click()

            images = driver.find_elements(By.XPATH, f' // *[ @ id = "etcimgSec"] / div[1] / div[2] / div / li /img')
            for i, img in enumerate(images):
                if i == IMG_COUNT:
                    break
                url = img.get_attribute('src')
                if not os.path.isdir(save_path):
                    os.makedirs(save_path)
                urllib.request.urlretrieve(url, save_path + f"/{i}.jpg")
            print("saved images to " + save_path)
            print("===================")
        except exceptions.StaleElementReferenceException as e:
            print(f"An error occurred: {e}")
        except exceptions.NoSuchElementException:
            print("Element not found")
            break
        except Exception as e:
            print(f"An error occurred: {e}")
            break

    end = time.time()  
    print(f"{end - start:.5f} sec")
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the issue is the `driver.refresh()` call. The first element is found, then you refresh the driver, and suddenly all other elements in the list you are iterating over become stale. If you need to refresh the driver inside your loop, you might need to fetch the elements again after each refresh.

To make it more clear what I mean, the `href = event.find_element(By.CSS_SELECTOR, 'a')` call during the second iteration throws the error if I'm right. The `event`is stale because the driver was refreshed in the previous iteration. Do you need to refresh the driver?

Edited Code:

As it wasn't the driver.refresh, I am not sure what the problem is and I can't run your code myself at the moment to check it myself. Try reloading the elements each iteration (just to see if that fixes the problem)

```
html_events = get_events()
# save img files to disk
for i in range(len(html_events)):
    try:
        html_events = get_events()
        event = events[i]
        print(event.text)
        # enter rest of you code here...
```

If the reason for the error is that the elements become stale after scrolling, then this should not throw the same error. If there is a different issue, like new elements appearing after scrolling, then this will give you a different behavior. Note that this is really just a quick an dirty check to see where the issue lies.

Comment: driver.refresh() code is my mistake, but I still got the same error.
I want to access web element sequentially

Comment: I have a page that has a scroll feature that requires me to load the entire web element.
It seems like there are a lot of unnecessary calls to make each time.
modified blow code
driver.back()
html_events = get_events()

Comment: See my edit, I am not exactly sure what causes the problem but maybe my code above can help you find the exact issue

Comment: Thank you for your advice. Your code above is help me a lot.